# What should $PYTHONHOME be set to on a Mac

Tags: python, macos

I don't have anything set in my .bash_profile for `$PYTHONHOME`.  What should this be set to?  Can't find anything consistent online to what it should be set to.

Comment: PYTHONHOME actually points to the directory of the standard library by default (e.g. /usr/local/lib/pythonXX).

Comment: It depends on what version of python do you use. I am ok with default one installed through homebrew so I do not have any PYTHONHOME in any of my config files. Which version of python do you use and for what purposes?

Comment: I use python 2.7 for command line scripts.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to set `$PYHONHOME` for python 2.7. Python knows where to find its standard library. If `$PYHONHOME` is not set, Python defaults to using the directory where python.exe was found, so that dir should be in PATH.

You can read [Environment variables](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) and [PYTHONHOME](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) in Python documentation.

The only reason to set `$PYTHONPATH` in the system is to maintain directories of custom Python libraries that you do not want to install in the global default location (i.e., the `site-packages` directory).